# Text search to return only relevant subdocuments

Tags: mongodb

My Document structure:

```
{ 
    data : {
        "0" : {
                 "title" : "example1",...
         },
        "1" : {
                 "title" : "example2",...
         }
}
```

I've created a `Text index` on this document:

```
db.collection.createIndex({"$**" : "text"}, {name: "collIndex"})
```

now when running a `Text query`

```
db.collection.find({$text : {$search: "example1"}})
```

I'm getting back the full `Document`. is it possible to get only the subDocument that contains the relevant text data? for example for the query mentioned above will result in

```
 { "0" : {"title" : "example1",...} ..}
```

--- EDIT ---

same question with data an an array:

```
data : [{title: "example1"..}, {title : "example2"}]
```

can i get only the array entries that contains the `text query`?

Comment: @chridam thanks for your answer. and if we assume that `data` is an `Array` then it's possible to get only the relevant array entries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Queries in MongoDB return documents, not subdocuments. For some types of queries, it is possible to return the first matching array element, but this is not the case for text queries. Normally you'd be able to use the aggregation pipeline to extract all matching array elements, but this is also not possible with a text index. If you want queries to match subdocuments, you should redesign your schema so the subdocuments are full-fledged documents.